# How do I save the Monero blockchain to another hard drive?

Tags: blockchain, windows

I have a small SSD as my windows 7 C: drive. How can I transfer and save the Monero blockchain to another hard drive on my computer in order to save space?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to pebx's answer, note that the default directory on Windows is %programdata%\bitmonero at least in v10.0. Move this entire directory to drive of your choosing and then run the command described:

> monerod.exe --data-dir D:\desired\path\to\your\blockchain

If you ran Monero v.9.4 or prior, you can also save space by deleting the entire LMDB directory and re-syncing from scratch which typically takes a few hours on a fast connection with a modern computer. Monero v10.0 uses less space for the database.

Answer (score 5):

Just move the data directory to the other hard drive and then launch monerod with the --data-dir flag from command line:

> monerod.exe --data-dir D:\desired\path\to\your\blockchain