# How to make a symlink to an external drive?

Tags: blockchain-data

I have an external drive that I want to store my blockchain on. I gather that I can make a symlink to my .bitmonero folder so the blockchain automatically gets stored on the external drive but I don't know how to do it. Can anyone walk me through setting this up?

Comment: This question isn't related to Monero at all; it's a question related to Win/*nix. And it sounds like you are solving the wrong problem. `monerod` can be configured to [use another data directory](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2270/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as Link Ng said "This question isn't related to Monero at all; it's a question related to Win/*nix."

Comment: In addition, it'd probably be easier to use the `--data-dir` flag. See: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7225/how-do-i-move-the-blockchain-data-mdb-to-a-different-directory-during-or-afte

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most portable approach is provided by **dEBYUNE** above. The **--data-dir** can also be defined in the monero node's configuration file so it does not have to be passed as an argument of the **monerod** CLI.

Otherwise, a UNIX only approach is provided below.

**Step 0** - make sure monerod is not running

**Step 1** - make sure the owners, groups and permissions of the external directory are the same or appropriate for your system's permission security model.

**Step 2** - make a relative path tape archive (tar) file of your ~/.bitmonero file.

`% cd ~`

`% tar cvf /your_desired_external_drive_path/.bitmonero.tar .bitmonero`

`% cd /your_desired_external_drive_path`

`% tar xvf .bitmonero.tar`

**Step 3** - rename your original .bitmonero directory. (Can delete after step 6 after confirming monerod is functioning reliably.)

`% cd ~`

`% mv .bitmonero original.bitmonero`

**Step 4** - make a relative .bitmonero directory link

`% ln /your_desired_external_drive_path/.bitmonero .bitmonero`

**Step 5** - confirm link was made properly by:

`% ls -l .bitmonero`

**Step 6** - start your monero daemon the way you did previously, in this case **--data-dir** becomes optional.